# Eclipse Juno - How to make it aware of classes and function in remote project?

Tags: php, eclipse, remote-access

I have created a connection in Eclipse within Remote System Explorer perspective.

I can reach the the files on the server.

Unfortunately autocompletion doesn't seem to work and the IDE isn't aware of classes and functions residing in project files.

How can I tackle this kind of projects (remote) in order to get the above mentioned (autocompletion, classes, functions) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at "**Fixing PHP autocomplete with Remote System Explorer**" here: http://www.patrickjwaters.com/blog/2011-07-24/how-setup-eclipse-php-pdt-remote-system-explorer-theme-manager-and-drupal-plugins/35